# VBA code for find cell data in another sheet and update it

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet1 - which is master file for customers.
Sheet2 - Gets updated weekly with any new customers. What I want is if any new customers on Sheet2 then they needs to be updated on sheet1.

You will see on image - 3 new customers on sheet2, which I want to have it on sheet1.

Please help with VBA code, which picks up new data from sheet2 and update sheet1. Just need data from column A from sheet2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't need VBA for that.  Search for help with the Excel worksheet function `VLOOKUP` or perhaps you could use `INDEX` and `MATCH`.  This is a very basic, extremely common task for Excel. See this [**Excel VBA Tutorial**](//www.homeandlearn.org/) and also see the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site. Also don't forget to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!)

Comment: Are always all the customers from the sheet 1 in sheet 2? Or could some old customers be in sheet 1 but not in sheet 2 anymore?

Comment: Below code works fine provided by Karthick Gunasekaran. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with below

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim var, i As Variant
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim sheet2 As Worksheet
    Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    sheet1lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sheet2lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To sheet2lastrow
            var = Application.Match(sheet2.Range("A" & i), sheet1.Range("A:A"), 0)
            If IsError(var) Then
                sheet1.Range("A" & sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value
            End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

OP

[image]

Comment: Dear Karthick Gunasekaran,
I was able to upload that excel on office365 and that code is working fine for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Yagnesh Purohit, sounds good. Kindly mark it as answer if satisfied